# Return value inside fs.stat

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having an issue returning a value after determining something from `fs.stat()`, here is the example below:

```
function checkFile(fileName, type) {

   var status = false;

   // Get the stats assocatied to this file
   fs.stat(fileName, function (error, stats) {

      // get the time when the file was last modified
      var fileTime = moment(stats.mtime);

      if(type === "behind") {

        var query = moment(main.repoTime).isAfter(fileTime);

      } else if(type === "updated") {

        var query = moment(fileTime).isAfter(main.repoTime);

      }

      status = query;

    });

    return status;

}
```

What am I exactly doing wrong here? If I took `fs.stat` it works fine?

Comment: Asynchronous call means no ability to return. What you are doing is is like ordering a pizza over the phone and eating it as soon as you hang up. Not possible because you need to wait for it to be delivered.

Comment: `checkFile` should accept a callback it calls with the result, like nearly all NodeJS functions do. As a very, very much second-class option, use `fs.statSync`. But it's much better to embrace the asynchronous nature of things when doing Node programming...